# most efficient way to set dataframe column indexing to other columns

Tags: pandas, performance, dataframe, indexing, eval

I have a large Dataframe. One of my columns contains the name of others. I want to eval this colum and set in each row the value of the referenced column:

```
|A|B|C|Column|
|:|:|:|:-----|
|1|3|4|  B   |
|2|5|3|  A   |
|3|5|9|  C   |
```

Desired output:

```
|A|B|C|Column|
|:|:|:|:-----|
|1|3|4|  3   |
|2|5|3|  2   |
|3|5|9|  9   |
```

I am achieving this result using:

```
df.apply(lambda d: eval("d." + d['Column']), axis=1)
```

But it is very slow, even using swifter. Is there a more efficient way of performing this?

Answer (score 1):

For better performance, use `df.to_numpy()`:

```
In [365]: df['Column'] = df.to_numpy()[df.index, df.columns.get_indexer(df.Column)]

In [366]: df
Out[366]: 
   A  B  C Column
0  1  3  4      3
1  2  5  3      2
2  3  5  9      9
```

Comment: This method without the .to_numpy() goes sligthly faster. Any clue on why is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean by without to_numpy?

Comment: df['Column'] = df.to_numpy()[df.index, df.columns.get_indexer(df.Column)]
vs
df['Column'] = df['Column'].values[df.index, df.columns.get_indexer(df.Column)]

Comment: I meant:
vs 
df['Column'] = df.values[df.index, df.columns.get_indexer(df.Column)]

Answer (score 0):

For Pandas < 1.2.0, use `lookup`:

```
df['Column'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['Column'])
```

From `1.2.0+`, `lookup` is decprecated, you can just use a `for` loop:

```
df['Column'] = [df.at[idx, r['Column']] for idx, r in df.iterrows()]
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  Column
0  1  3  4       3
1  2  5  3       2
2  3  5  9       9
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `lookup` is going to decprecated try `numpy` method with `get_indexer`

```
df['new'] = df.values[df.index,df.columns.get_indexer(df.Column)]
df
Out[75]: 
   A  B  C Column new
0  1  3  4      B   3
1  2  5  3      A   2
2  3  5  9      C   9
```